# How to log using ILogger provided by Azurefunction in external assemblies

Tags: c#, azure, function, logging, ilogger

Inside azure function , we get ILogger instance to log, which works fine. We are pushing logs to application insights by configuring instrumentation key in function app settings.

however I am not able to pass this ILogger to other assemblies , this function is referencing from the solution. How can I log information inside external assemblies through this azure function.

anyone worked on this?

Comment: Why can't you pass it to your external assemblies (if you have them under your control / you write them)?

Comment: Can you show us some code examples?

Answer (score 0):

ILogger class used by the Azure Functions comes from the package 
Microsoft.Extensions.Logging. Assuming your external assemblies had this reference, you should be able to pass it to your external assemblies.

If that is not the case, you can use TelemetryClient and send data to Application Insights directly, just make sure you've specified the same InstrumentationKey that is being used for the application insights.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-custom-events-metrics